# Taking a user input as a string variable containing a wild card expression

Tags: c++, bash, unix, ubuntu-16.04

I have written a bash script which does the following:

1. Ask user to input the path of the directory containing all CSVs.
2. Run a C++ script that does takes each CSV and do some processing on it

    `echo "Enter the path where all the CSVs are stored"
   read varname`

The problem is now when I do `$varname` and pass it to my C++ code, it's not getting interpreted as a string. Only the first value is being passed which makes sense but I am unable to figure out how to send the varname as a single string. For example, if I enter `path_to_CSVs/*.csv`, then I want to pass this value in this format `"path_to_CSVs/*.csv"`to my C++ program.

I am not an expert in bash scripting, so can someone please help?

Comment: `./yourProgram "$varname"`.

Comment: @Socowi Thanks "$varname" wokred. Also, thanks for that link. It's a great answer